# How to show a user-friendly error message when you can not serve a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, yii2

I have a small app that serves a text file when a user clicks a download button. The problem is, if some fields in the database are missing, the download should fail, the file won't be sent and the user should receive an error message that explains what went wrong. My app is written using Yii2 but the specific framework does not matter. How can I show a nice pretty error message to the user? Right now I just throw a "404 not found exception". What are possible solutions to my problem, either server-side or client-side?

Comment: Shouldn't be a 404 anyway - so throw a 500 and put the details in the reason.

Comment: Alternatively, provide a separate method to check the DB fields first.

Comment: Oh, I check the fields first, I just do not know how to nicely tell a user he can not download this file.

Comment: check if the returned rows from the database are missing the required entries, set a boolean from this information and check it clientside on return...  display an alert or modal dialog on the condition that the file is missing...  i guess i don't really understand your question beyond this...

Comment: You may check first, but it looks like you only have a *single* call : User clicks button / client requests document / server checks and fails or returns document.   It should be *two* calls : User clicks button / client requests a check / server returns to client that all is ok / client requests document.  If server returns that it's not ok, show that to the user before requesting the document itself.

Comment: Or are you asking how to do (a nice version of) `alert("Document is not available.");` in javascript?

Comment: I am sorry that I can not properly express myself, you touched upon what I really want: how should I create these alerts or modal windows for the user? I see two solutions: either redirect user to a pretty error page with some info, but I don't want the user to leave the original page. Another is to request file download using AJAX when the user clicks a button and see if the response contains an error code or a file, but then the file will be delivered to AJAX code as a response content, not as a downloaded file, will it? What do I do with it then?

Comment: Personally, I always download files via an anchor with `target='_blank'` so that it opens in a new tab - if there's an error it will be shown in the new tab and user gets a form of progress.  Trying to download a file to ajax and *then* present to the user adds its own complexities.  In this case I wouldn't even show the download link (or show as disabled) as you should be doing the check separately from the download.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a flash message on the top of your view.
Refer to the following link to get an understanding.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/

You can add a flash message by just adding any of these lines.

`Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data1 saved!");
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', "Data2 failed!");
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('notice', "Data3 ignored.");`

And you can call it in a preferred place of your view as follows.calling it at top is advisable.

```
<?php
foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: CAn you give a bit more detail instead of only posting a link? Otherwise, if the linked page goes offline, your answer is no longer of use